# Convert pence into another currency if I only know dollars

Tags: algorithms

Say I have the following conversion currencies:

USDUSD: 1,
USDGBP: 0.772499,
USDEUR: 0.891986

And I want to convert 0.95 into Euros.

I need to first work out what 0.95 pence is in dollars and then to Euros

0.95 x 0.772499 x 0.891986

Am I correct?

Comment: What is 0.95? Usd, gbp, EUR? If it is gbp, why have you multiplied it with the usd to gbp rate?

Comment: 0.95 is GBP currency

Comment: If $r$ is the conversion rate of currency A to B, then $1/r$ is the conversion rate of B to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your conversion is not correct. Since
$$\mbox{USD}=0.772499\,\mbox{GBP}\quad\mbox{and}
\quad \mbox{USD}=0.891986\,\mbox{EUR}$$
it follows that 
$$0.95\,\mbox{GBP}=0.95\,\mbox{GBP}\cdot \frac{\mbox{USD}}{0.772499\,\mbox{GBP}} \cdot \frac{0.891986\,\mbox{EUR}}{\mbox{USD}}=1.096942\,\mbox{EUR}.$$